# Dynamic reference to trait with generic without specifying generic in Rust

Tags: rust

Is it possible to have a variable that contains something conforming to a trait with a generic without needing to specify the generic?

A common feature of interfaces and polymorphism in other languages such as Java and JavaScript is the ability to handle an instance just based on the interface it implements. In the following code, I've created a `Site` trait and a `make_site` factory for creating an instance that implements the `Site` trait. The `Site` trait has a generic associated with it, but the code that handles the `Site` can treat `E` opaquely -- it simply needs to keep track of it and pass it back to other functions of the same `Site` instance.

```rust
pub struct CrawlResult<E> {
    pub discovered_queue_entries: Vec<E>,
    pub result: Option<String>,
}

pub trait Site<E> {
    fn start_queue(&self) -> Vec<E>;
    fn crawl(&self, queue_entry: &E) -> CrawlResult<E>;
}

fn make_site<E>() -> Box<dyn Site<E>> {
    if rand::random() {
        Box::new(SiteA { add: 100 })
    } else {
        Box::new(SiteB { sub: 1 })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let site = make_site();

    process(&site);
}
```

I have elided some of the supporting code to try to highlight the parts that seem most relevant, but there's a full reproducible example [in the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4acb52a63066f77eafe1c16ae1331819).

The above code fails to compile in the `make_site` function.

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `SiteA: Site<E>` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:103:9
    |
103 |         Box::new(SiteA { add: 100 })
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Site<E>` is not implemented for `SiteA`
    |
    = note: required for the cast from `Box<SiteA>` to `Box<(dyn Site<E> + 'static)>`
help: consider introducing a `where` clause, but there might be an alternative better way to express this requirement
    |
101 | fn make_site<E>() -> Box<dyn Site<E>> where SiteA: Site<E> {
    |                                       ++++++++++++++++++++

error[E0277]: the trait bound `SiteB: Site<E>` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:105:9
    |
105 |         Box::new(SiteB { sub: 1 })
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Site<E>` is not implemented for `SiteB`
    |
    = note: required for the cast from `Box<SiteB>` to `Box<(dyn Site<E> + 'static)>`
help: consider introducing a `where` clause, but there might be an alternative better way to express this requirement
    |
101 | fn make_site<E>() -> Box<dyn Site<E>> where SiteB: Site<E> {
    |                                       ++++++++++++++++++++

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Box<dyn Site<_>>: Site<_>` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:112:13
    |
112 |     process(&site);
    |             ^^^^^ the trait `Site<_>` is not implemented for `Box<dyn Site<_>>`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `Site<E>`:
              <SiteA as Site<SiteAEntry>>
              <SiteB as Site<SiteBEntry>>
    = note: required for the cast from `&Box<dyn Site<_>>` to `&dyn Site<_>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to 3 previous errors
```

This code is in support of a web crawler and the idea is that every site will have a different strategy for crawling it. `E` would typically be an enum type that describes an entry on the crawl queue and would be different depending on the site crawled. It seems like most of the problems arise from the generic crawl entry type, but it would simply not be possible to define a `Site` implementation if we could not have that generic.

Are these established patterns translatable to Rust, or are they just impossible to implement in Rust?

Comment: Even in Java, you cannot consider that a first interface with a declared function returning a list of integers and a second interface with the same declared function but returning a list of strings are equivalent. If it was so, what would be expected when calling such function? integers or strings?

Comment: That's true and it may also be impossible to implement this pattern in Java as well. My experience lately has been more around dynamic languages where a contract such as "this generic will be consistent when dealing with this API" is guaranteed by the programmer instead of the compiler. Something like this would be trivial to implement in JavaScript or Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a variable that contains something conforming to a trait with a generic without needing to specify the generic?

Only if the type implements some trait that you can specify, and where all branches use the same type.  In your case, neither of these things are true.

```
fn make_site<E>() -> Box<dyn Site<E>>
```

This signature allows the *caller* to decide what `E` is. What happens if they call `make_site::<String>()`?  What you want is a way for the function itself to say what `E` is.  You can do this without actually specifying the inner type by returning `Box<dyn Site<impl SiteEntry>>` and making sure the generic type implements `SiteEntry`.  You would also remove the generic type `E` from the function.

Note this will limit what the caller can do with the type to only what `SiteEntry` provides.  Let's try that with an empty trait just to see if it works:

```
trait SiteEntry {}

impl SiteEntry for SiteAEntry {}
impl SiteEntry for SiteBEntry {}

fn make_site() -> Box<dyn Site<impl SiteEntry>> {
    // ...
```

We've traded one error for another.  Now, we get this instead:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `SiteB: Site<SiteAEntry>` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:109:9
    |
109 |         Box::new(SiteB { sub: 1 })
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Site<SiteAEntry>` is not implemented for `SiteB`
    |
    = help: the trait `Site<SiteBEntry>` is implemented for `SiteB`
    = help: for that trait implementation, expected `SiteBEntry`, found `SiteAEntry`
    = note: required for the cast from `Box<SiteB>` to `Box<(dyn Site<SiteAEntry> + 'static)>`
```

Now we're running into the second constraint I mentioned above: all branches need to return the same type.  Here we have the first branch returning `Box<dyn Site<SiteAEntry>>`, which is totally fine, but the compiler then infers that the other branch must also return `Box<dyn Site<SiteAEntry>>` and rightly complains that `SiteB` does not implement `Site<SiteAEntry>`, so the cast is impossible.

Your options here are somewhat limited.  One option would be to create a type-erased version of `Site` that has no generic argument, and works solely with trait objects:

```
trait ErasedSite {
    fn start_queue(&self) -> Vec<Box<dyn SiteEntry>>;
    fn crawl(&self, queue_entry: &dyn SiteEntry) -> CrawlResult<Box<dyn SiteEntry>>;
}
```

Then your `make_site` function can return `Box<dyn ErasedSite>` (provided you create a corresponding newtype with an `ErasedSite` implementation).

This approach will require `SiteEntry` implement a method allowing you to determine what type of entry you have, and probably other methods as well.

What you're looking for is possible in Rust, but it's likely that this particular approach may not actually be what you want.  As an example, `Site` probably should not actually be generic, but instead allow an implementation to define the entry type using associated types:

```
trait Site {
    type Entry;

    fn start_queue(&self) -> Vec<Self::Entry>;
    fn crawl(&self, queue_entry: &Self::Entry) -> CrawlResult<Self::Entry>;
}
```

This is usually preferred unless you envision one type implementing `Site<E>` multiple times with different types for `E`.

Note this doesn't ultimately solve the problem you ran into, it just moves it -- when you say `dyn SomeTrait` you are *required* to include `SomeTrait`'s associated types, so you would need to say `Box<dyn Site<Entry = impl SiteEntry>>` and then you're right back where you started.

Ultimately, you really have two options:

- Type-erase everything and put all of the capabilities that a site's entry type must have behind a trait like `SiteEntry`.  (This is runtime dynamic dispatch.)
- Use an enum to contain the various kinds of sites.  This may or may not work depending on what exactly you're trying to do.  (This is compile-time dynamic dispatch.)

Which you choose might be a matter of taste, performance characteristics, or simplicity of the programming model.